# tkinter - dock and undock frame with wm_manage and wm_forget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I found the following in the [tk docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M66):

> The wm manage and wm forget commands may be used to perform undocking
> and docking of windows.

So I tried [wm_manage](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M53) and [wm_forget](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M40) in this code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class MyFigure(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        self.bc = tk.Button(self, text='confi',
                            command=lambda:self.configure(bg='red')
                            )
        self.bmanage = tk.Button(self, text='manage',
                                 command = lambda:self.master.wm_manage(self)
                                 )
        self.bforget = tk.Button(self, text='forget',
                                 command = lambda:self.master.wm_forget(self)
                                 )

        self.bmanage.pack(side='left')
        self.bc.pack(side='left')
        self.bforget.pack(side='left')

mf = MyFigure(root)
mf.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

But it dosen't worked out. So I readed more and there is no way I can missunderstand this:

> A toplevel widget may be used as a frame and managed with any of the
> other geometry managers after using the wm forget command.

So I tried to do something like that:

```
def _manage(self):
    top = self.master.wm_manage(self)
    print(top)
def _forget(self):
    frame = self.master.wm_forget(self)
    print(frame)
```

But both return `None`. Am I something missing here? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make `wm_forget` correctly work, you should pass  a toplevel window as argument. For instance, if you add the following lines in the constructor of the class:

```
self.top = tk.Toplevel()
self.top.title("Top level")
```

You can then call the method as follows:

```
self.master.wm_forget(self.top)
```

Regarding the `wm_manage`, you should pass as argument the widget you want to convert to a stand alone top-level window. Please keep in mind that you can only use this command with `frame`, `labelframe` and `toplevel` widgets. If you apply this command to your main window `Tk`, nothing will happen.

A full example converting a frame to a toplevel (pressing button `manage`) and converting it back to frame (pressing button `forget`):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class MyFigure(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        self.bc = tk.Button(self, text='confi',
                            command=lambda:self.configure(bg='red')
                            )
        self.bmanage = tk.Button(self, text='manage',
                                 command = lambda:self._manage()
                                 )
        self.bforget = tk.Button(self, text='forget',
                                 command = lambda:self._forget()
                                 )

        self.bmanage.pack(side='left')
        self.bc.pack(side='left')
        self.bforget.pack(side='left')
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master, bg="red", height=100)
        self.label=tk.Label(self.frame, text="hi")
        self.frame.pack()
        self.label.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    def _manage(self):
        test=self.master.wm_manage(self.frame)

    def _forget(self):
        self.master.wm_forget(self.frame)
        self.frame.pack()

mf = MyFigure(root)
mf.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `command = lambda:self._manage()` can be simplified to `command=self._manage`