# tkinter - undock frame and handle window close event

Tags: python, tkinter, events, window

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111155/how-do-i-handle-the-window-close-event-in-tkinter), I wrote the following mwe:

```
import tkinter as tk


class BaseFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
      
        self.bmanage = tk.Button(self, text='undock', command = self.undock)
        self.bforget = tk.Button(self, text='dock', command = self.dock)

        self.bmanage.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky='nsew')
        self.bforget.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=20, sticky='nsew')

        self.dockable_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="red", height=100)
        self.dockable_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')
        self.label = tk.Label(self.dockable_frame, text="hi")
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=150, pady=20, sticky='nsew')

    def undock(self):
        self.parent.wm_manage(self.dockable_frame)
        self.dockable_frame.configure(bg='blue')

        print(type(self.dockable_frame))

    def dock(self):
        self.parent.wm_forget(self.dockable_frame)
        self.dockable_frame.grid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()

    base_frame = BaseFrame(root)
    base_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky='nsew')
    
    root.mainloop()
```

By clicking the **undock** button, the red frame is undocked and by clicking the **dock** button, the frame is docked again. I have two questions:

1. Why is the type of self.dockable_frame a **<class 'tkinter.Frame'>** and not a TopLevel since the [wm manage documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.html#M53) says: *The widget specified will become a stand alone top-level window*?
2. How can I handle the window close event since *self.dockable_frame.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", insert_function_here)* gives an error on my Windows pc?

The error is:
AttributeError: 'Frame' object has no attribute 'protocol'
I understand the error but how to handle the window close event?

Comment: you can probably `self.dockable_frame.bind('<Destroy>', insert_function_here)` to handle destroying; as to why it is not specifically a `Toplevel`? the documentation doesn't say it has to become a `Toplevel`, just a top level window which it does become

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the type of self.dockable_frame a <class 'tkinter.Frame'> and not a TopLevel since the wm manage documentation says: The widget specified will become a stand alone top-level window?

I think it is because `self.dockable_frame` is a python class and doesn't know that the underlying widget has been changed. Arguably this is a bug in `wm_manage`.

> How can I handle the window close event since self.dockable_frame.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", insert_function_here) gives an error on my Windows PC?

The simplest way is to call the method directly from the `tk.Wm` class. It would look like this:

```
tk.Wm.protocol(self.dockable_frame, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.whatever)
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is missleading. [As I discovered this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63345390/tkinter-dock-and-undock-frame-with-wm-manage-and-wm-forget) I thought simliar, the frame becomes a window. In fact that isnt really true which I can proof by my code below.

What really happens, at least under MS-Windows but I expect same functionality under other os, is that frames will be just packed on a different toplevel that will be created by wm_mange for this.

When tkinter defines a [Window/Toplevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-windows#creating-a-main-window) it always build a [child window (frame)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-windows#creating-enumerating-and-sizing-child-windows) for the [client area](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-windows#client-area) which you will work with. Thats why you need to call the win32gui.[GetParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getparent) method when you will [change your window style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69603075/tkinter-customization-on-high-level/69605702#69605702).

**Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import win32gui

def info():
    print(f'python id: {id(frame)}')
    print(f'tkinterID: {frame.winfo_id()}')
    print(f'parent id: {win32gui.GetParent(frame.winfo_id())}')
def undock():
    root.wm_manage(frame)
def forget():
    root.wm_forget(frame)
    frame.pack()

root = tk.Tk()
frame= tk.Frame()
frame.pack()

b1 = tk.Button(frame,text='INFO',command=info)
b2 = tk.Button(frame,text='mnge',command=undock)
b3 = tk.Button(frame,text='nrml',command=forget)
b1.pack()
b2.pack()
b3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

*By first appearance*:

```
python id: 67118160
tkinterID: 3412074
parent id: 7867926
```

*after undock*

```
python id: 67118160
tkinterID: 3412074
parent id: 15666896
```

*after forget*

```
python id: 67118160
tkinterID: 3412074
parent id: 7867926
```

[reference](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/125.md):

> In Tk, Toplevel windows are basically a special form of a Frame which
> are managed by the window manager. The proposal is to add the commands
> wm manage and wm forget which will take an arbitrary Frame and allow
> it to be managed by the window manager, making it a Toplevel window.